# linear gradient to entire list vs just each word

Tags: css, linear-gradients

I have a list as an inline navigation that I'm adding a gradient color to. Right now the gradient is effecting each link individually though. I would like it to effect the list from the first word to the last. Code below:

CSS:

```
ul li {
    display: inline;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0 0 0 40px;
}

ul li a {
    position: relative;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #30CFD0 0%, #330867 100%);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gy7hqevm/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to apply the background to the `ul` element instead. And you probably need a class or ID to distinguish your navigation from other `ul`s.

Comment: Thanks. That seems to work if they're not links but since the list is all links they're becoming invisible if I put that code on the ul.

Comment: Ok, got it to work by completely removing the ul li a { css and adding the gradient code to just the ul like you suggested. But now the ul li a:hover { css won't work even if I add !important;